# use the same memory to do LU decomposition in armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have question to solve linear system using armadillo. A*x=b. But my A matrix is pretty big. It is arma::cx_mat A(40000,40000). When I run x=arma::solve(A,b), armadillo will try to allocate a new memory to store A, and then use the new memory to do LU decomposition and will not use the memory that store the original A. The definition of solve can be found in fn_solve.hpp. But you already see my A is pretty big. Allocate a new memory will consume all the memory quickly. For my problem, I do not need the original A any more. So can I use some method to let armadillo to use the original memory for A to do LU decomposition?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use LAPACK directly, instead of going through Armadillo.  I suggest you have a look at how Armadillo prepares data and calls the underlying LAPACK functions to implement solve(). This is in the file include/armadillo_bits/auxlib_meat.hpp

EDIT: Armadillo developers are usually receptive to patches. If you come up with a solution, send them a patch or the modified files.